# GridView OnRowUpdating unable to get values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that needs to have an editable column in each row. I have declared it as shown below.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="TestGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" SkinID="GridViewNew" AllowSorting="False"
        OnRowDataBound="GridViewTest_RowDataBound" EnableViewState="True" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridViewTest_OnRowUpdating" OnRowEditing="GridViewTest_OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridViewTest_OnRowCancelingEdit"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stock" HeaderText="Stock" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DutyStatus" InsertVisible="False" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="standLbl" runat="server"><%#Eval("DutyStatus").ToString().Trim() %></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlDutyStatus" runat="server" 
                        DataTextField="DutyStatus"
                        DataValueField="DutyStatus">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Percentage" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="enhanced">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="enhLbl" runat="server"><%#Eval("percentage").ToString().Trim() %></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TbPercentage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("percentage").ToString().Trim()%>' class="edit-field"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The Data is displayed as it should be. The problem arises when trying to edit the Percentage value. Clicking 'Update' works fine and the editable TextBox within the cell is displayed, however when the value has been modified and 'Update' is clicked, when the `GridViewTest_OnRowUpdating` method is hit, the object sender and `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` are both empty. The method is defined as below.

```
    protected void GridViewTest_OnRowUpdating(object ASender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs AE)
    {
        PerformDataTableUpdate(ref TestGrid, AE);
    }
```

In the above method; object ASender has no rows, `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` AE properties are all empty (Keys, NewValues, OlValues etc).
I have ensured that the GridView is not getting rebound in Page_Load or anywhere else (it is empty when it enters and leaves `Page_load`  and still empty when it hits `GridViewTest_OnRowUpdating` on update postback).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When updating values using GridView, you need to set the [**`DataKeyNames`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Once this is specified Gridview uses the keys to *uniquely identify* which rows needs to be updated/deleted

`DataKeyNames` is usually set to the Primary Keys of the table but we are not bound to do that always.

MSDN Says:

> You must set the DataKeyNames property in order for the automatic update and delete features of the GridView control to work. The values of these key fields are passed to the data source control in order to specify the row to update or delete

**EDIT::**

> 1.) GridViewUpdateEventArgs AE properties are all empty (Keys, NewValues, OlValues etc)

Now there's a condition that GridView will only use the `DatakeyNames` and populate the [**`Old`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx) and [**`New`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) values ONLY when data is bound using `DataSourceID` property. This is by design.

> 2.) object ASender has no rows

I suspect this happening because of data binding to gridview not being done in a correct way.

Below are some common discussions/resolutions around this issue::

1.) Since data is bind to gridview at runtime, make sure you bind it as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       GridView1.DataSource = ds; // appropriate data source here
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Why DataBind() the above way? ::

> After clicking the "Update" button, `Page_Load()` event gets fired before `OnRowUpdating()` event. Therefore if you *MISS* using the `IsPostback` property, `GridView` is getting bound( Refreshed ) again with the Original values(i.e. OldValues)

This is required so that in our `onRowUpdating` event we get the New values we submitted earlier.

2.) Getting values from Rows:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
   {
       GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
       TextBox FirstName= (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFirstName");
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I've spent the last day trying to figure it out, I have other GridViews set up the same way in the site and they worked fine without the DataKeyNames being specified but I'm guessing it's related to the table used here having no primary key.

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon, do you have any idea why only the old values are displayed in the GridViewUpdateEventArgs? ASender is unfortunately still empty (no rows) on hitting the GridViewTest_OnRowUpdating method.

Comment: @Matthew: Please see my  Edits. Hope they help you understand further the issue here

Comment: Thanks for the additions to the answer, unfortunately it's not that the grid is getting re-bound on post-back, only within a check on !IsPostBack and in the OnRowEditing, OnRowUpdating and OnRowCancelling event handlers. I have a break-point right at the start of Page_Load and there are no rows in the GridView at that point on any post back.